# Angular events with multiple methods

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

Working on a custom input component with ControlValueAccessor and cannot find guidance on the best way to access the input value. Since [passing $event is a dubious practice](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice) is there a way to trigger two or more methods when an event is fired?

```
<input type='text' (input)="onChange($event.target.value); watchCity($event.target.value)" [disabled]="disabled" (onEnter)="onEnter($event)" (blur)="onTouched()"  />
```

Maybe there is a better way to get the value from inside the ControlValueAccessor component?

Comment: Just to note: passing `$event` is not dubious as a rule. It's dubious in their example because in the event handling method, they access `event.target` and that method thus knows too much intricacies of the template.

Comment: I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you have should work, but it is not very common.

You can call one function that calls both of the others.

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' 
       (input)="onChange($event.target.value)" 
       [disabled]="disabled" 
       (onEnter)="onEnter($event.target.value)" 
       (blur)="onTouched()"  />
```

**Component**

```
  onChange(value) {
    // do whatever else
    this.watchCity(value);
  }
```

Stackblitz is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9wqhjp

Also, looking here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement I don't see an `onEnter` event for an input element?

And you mentioned something about a `ControlValueAccessor`. Are you trying to build one? If so, check out this: https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/ for an example.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful comment! Yes delegating the value from one method was the key for me. Thank you again.